# Changing job due to unhappiness

Tags: job-change, employer

I graduated in June 2016 and started working in October 2016 for a big consultancy firm. However, after my short experience with my current employer, I feel terribly unhappy and bored since I almost did not learn anything at all. I am constantly looking at new vacancies and I have found some that really interest me (no consultancy for me anymore).

However, I do not really know how to properly address this in my cover letter? On one hand, I really want to express in some way that I am looking for something more challenging and that my current employer does not give me the possibility. On the other hand, I certainly do not want to break down my current employer since it can give a wrong impression.

Furthermore, suppose that I am invited to an interview, how to address this? They will certainly ask me about my reason to leave etc. and I want to express that I tried very hard to learn but that my former employer did not give me the chance. Should I be truly honest here? I don't want they to think that I did not try hard enough or that I am a "job hopper". I just want to do something that I like and work for an employer that gives me the chance to improve and develop myself.

All hints are welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, the positive thing is that I like to work for this company. The negative thing is that I really hate the work content. I thought consultancy would be great to broaden my knowledge. However, I have always known very well what I wanted to do in my professional life so I am starting to notice that consultancy is not suited for me. 

This would be something good to say during an interview imo. I would however not mention the above in my cover letter.

Comment: What industry are you in? knowing this would help me to answer you better, especially if you are in IT line.

Comment: I am working in Financial Services and Risk Managament in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the resume, put what you did and what you learned, even if it was just a little. Don't explain why you left, or put as little detail as possible in the resume/application. Let it come up organically in the interview.

If they ask you in the interview, simply state what you did here: The job wasn't what I expected when I went in, and I want to make sure at this point in my career I'm working somewhere that I want to be for a long time. As usual, I advocate not talking about how the other company failed. That can come across as petty under certain circumstances.

Instead, focus on you wanting to learn more and be more of an asset to the new company. This puts you in a positive light, and gets across the point that you want to learn. This positive attitude is a great way to interest the employer and also gives you a brighter start with the new company instead of dragging along a negative view from a previous company.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to claim that the company doesn't offer opportunities to learn when you're so new in your position that you still haven't quite learned everything about the job (typically takes at least a year).

If I were you I would say that you don't think the company is a good fit for you. When they ask why you could say that the company culture is such that work-life balance is not taken into consideration, or that the position was advertised as X, but that the role was misrepresented, and you're doing more of Y, which is not what you're interested in.

Comment: Or may be say something about consultancy not being as enjoyable as you thought? I think people have a fair understanding that consultancy isn't everyone's cup of tea.

Comment: @matthelliwell "enjoyable"  might be a bad word to use. It's work, not R&R. Something in line of "I learned that consultancy is not my field and I expect that I can be more effective at *insert new company's field here*" would be much safer.